# Make content visible after PayPal payment?

Tags: php, database, paypal, payment-processing

I am making a website where you can have 2 types of articles: free and paid.
Each user has it's own profile.
When user purchases certain article it is visible to him when he is logged in.
For starters I was thinking of using PayPal to process my payments.

THE QUESTION IS:
How to make this process automatic?
I know how to do it manually but not a practical solution.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Are you a php programmer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take a look at [Paypal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sdks/)

You can create a table to store payments in your database, a user can user a payment button on the page to pay for the content. Use paypal [PHP-PayPal-IPN](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN) to check if a payment status. If payment is complete you redirect to a php page to update the payment status on the  payment table and redirect to your information page.

Your payment table could include:

```
|id|payment_code|user_id|amount|information_id|payment_date|payment_status
```

On your information page always check if payment is been made by user to display the paid content.

```
   //fetch payment status from payment_table where content_id = $content_id and user_id = $user_id
   // if status is paid then display content
```